# ctags use for Assembler

Tags: vim, ctags

I want to generate tags on Assembler project I'm working on, but ctags-5.6 doesn't seem to understand the macro definition of the assembler. Is there a way to explain ctags what pattern to use in order to determine a tag kind ?

Thanks.
Mark

Comment: 5.6 is outdated, the current version, 5.9 was released 4 or 5 years ago and supports ASM by default.

Answer (score 1):

At least about gas macro handling universal-ctags(https://ctags.io) is improved well.

(Universal-ctags)

```
[jet@localhost wan]$ ~/var/ctags/ctags -x -o - wanxlfw.S | grep macro
memcpy           macro       148 wanxlfw.S        .macro memcpy src, dest, len // len must be < 65536 bytes
memcpy_from_pci  macro       126 wanxlfw.S        .macro memcpy_from_pci src, dest, len // len must be < 8 MB
memcpy_from_pci  macro       168 wanxlfw.S        .macro memcpy_from_pci src, dest, len
memcpy_to_pci    macro       136 wanxlfw.S        .macro memcpy_to_pci src, dest, len
memcpy_to_pci    macro       173 wanxlfw.S        .macro memcpy_to_pci src, dest, len
wait_for_command macro       180 wanxlfw.S        .macro wait_for_command
```

(Exuberant-ctags)

```
[jet@localhost wan]$ ctags -x -o - wanxlfw.S | grep macro
```

Exuberant-ctags captures nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to generate a tags database for Assembler. The format is simple, see `:help tags-file-format`. The default tags program, *Exuberant Ctags* can be [extended with regular expressions](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/EXTENDING.html) (`--langmap`, `--regex`), but that probably only yields an approximate parsing for complex languages.

Better write / search for a dedicated executable for it. (There are precedents, like *jtags* for Java, and many of the *tag sidebar* plugins can be configured to use a custom tags program, too.)

Comment: Ingo, thanks for comment. I've added regex in my $HOME/.ctags, but something seems do not act properly. Basically my asm supports variable definition as 'vardef regtype NAME register', so I have "--regex-asm=/^[ \t]*vardef[ \t]+(regtype|volatile)+[ \t]+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+).*;/\2/d,defines/i"  Now  run ctags, but I get two lines in resulting TAGS, one is correctly parsed and tagged as 'D', the other is tagged as 'l' (label). What is possibly wrong?