# How to write .ctags file for assembly extention?

Tags: ctags, exuberant-ctags

I'm using exuberant ctag program for tagging.
I saw [ctags use for Assembler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424105/ctags-use-for-assembler) but couldn't exactly understand the link there.  So comparing with my extesion for system verilog, I added these lines for assembly, (I just need to parse ENTRY for macro definition), I added below to .ctags file.

```
--langdef=assembly
--langmap=assembly:.S
--regex-assembly=/^ENTRY(([a-zA-Z_0-9]+))$/\1/m,macro/
```

The sample assembly file (debug.S) is like this :

```
ENTRY(printch)
        addruart_current r3, r1, r2
        mov r1, r0
        mov r0, #0
        b   1b
ENDPROC(printch)
```

But I can't find printch in the tags file. What is wrong in the .ctags file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to define a new language. ctags has Asm parser.
Extending the parser is enough.
See how I use the backslash characters.

```
$ cat /tmp/debug.S
ENTRY(printch)
        addruart_current r3, r1, r2
        mov r1, r0
        mov r0, #0
        b   1b
ENDPROC(printch)
$ ctags --regex-Asm='/^ENTRY\(([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)\)$/\1/m,macro/'  -o - /tmp/debug.S
printch /tmp/debug.S    /^ENTRY(printch)$/;"    m
```

Comment: hi, in my ubuntu machine your method doesn't work.  ckim@ckim-ubuntu:~/U-BOOT/u-boot$ cat /tmp/debug.S
ENTRY(printch)
  addruart_current r3, r1, r2
  mov r1, r0
  mov r0, #0
  b 1b
ENDPROC(printch)
ckim@ckim-ubuntu:~/U-BOOT/u-boot$ `ctags --regex-Asm='/^ENTRY\((a-zA-Z_0-9]+)\)$/\1/m,macro/' -o - /tmp/debug.S` Just no output. What is your ctags version? Mine is Exuberant Ctags 5.9~svn20110310.

Comment: "Exuberant Ctags 5.8, Copyright (C) 1996-2009 Darren Hiebert
  Compiled: Jan 26 2021, 00:00:00". `[` is missed in your command line.

Comment: Ah, missing `[` was the problem. I added the --regex-Asm=  line in my .ctags and it works! Thank you!

Comment: hi I asked a question similart to this, could you read it give me an answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70387740/cant-figure-out-whats-wrong-with-ctag-regex-for-assembly-macro-extraction

Comment: YAMAO hello, can you look at my question and help please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71124536/cant-add-reg-expression-for-a-define-in-ctags