# Can't add reg expression for a #define in ctags

Tags: ctags

I can't figure out how to make ctags detect the __mrs_s definition. It doesn't add the search pattern so I can't find it in vi.

```
$cat /tmp/qq.h
int test(int i)
{
printf("Hello!");
return 0;
}

#define __mrs_s(v, r)                       \
    DEFINE_MRS_S                        \
"   mrs_s " v ", " __stringify(r) "\n"          \
    UNDEFINE_MRS_S

$ctags --regex-C++='/^#define \([a-zA-Z_0-9]+\)([a-zA-Z,\ ]+)[\t ]+/\1/d/'  -o - /tmp/qq.h
__mrs_s /tmp/qq.h   7;" d
test    /tmp/qq.h   /^int test(int i)$/;"   f
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `--excmd=pattern` option like:

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /tmp/qq.h 
int test(int i)
{
printf("Hello!");
return 0;
}

#define __mrs_s(v, r)                       \
    DEFINE_MRS_S                        \
"   mrs_s " v ", " __stringify(r) "\n"          \
    UNDEFINE_MRS_S


[root@localhost ~]# ctags --excmd=pattern -o - /tmp/qq.h 
__mrs_s /tmp/qq.h   /^#define __mrs_s(/;"   d
test    /tmp/qq.h   /^int test(int i)$/;"   f
```

Comment: Hi Masatake, thank you again. But I couldn't generate the tag from the original file. I'll be grateful if you could take some time to consider this new question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71174162/cant-generate-tag-mrs-s-from-define-mrs-sv-r-in-a-file-even-using