# can't generate tag __mrs_s from "#define __mrs_s(v, r)" in a file.. even using --excmd=pattern

Tags: ctags, exuberant-ctags

generating tags using ctags seems to be very tricky.
I wanted make tag file for https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.21/source/arch/arm64/include/asm/sysreg.h
you can get this `sysreg.h` file by

```
wget https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.21/source/arch/arm64/include/asm/sysreg.h
```

Please see [Can't add reg expression for a #define in ctags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71124536/cant-add-reg-expression-for-a-define-in-ctags/71162374#71162374). I tried the same method in this answer as below.

```
ctags --excmd=pattern sysreg.h
```

I see tag for `mrs_s` or `msr_s` in the generated `tags` file. But I don't see the tag for `__mrs_s` or `__msr_s` that I originally wanted.  What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no simple way to satisfy the goal.

sysreg.h contains assembly language code that makes the C++ indexer of ctags confused. See https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.21/source/arch/arm64/include/asm/sysreg.h#L741

(It would be nice to add a feature to the C++ indexer to skip `__ASSEMBLY__` and `__ASSEMBLER__` area.)

I found one hacky technique that works only with Universal ctags (https://ctags.io). Your ctags may be Exuberant Ctags. So the technique I will write here may not work with your ctags.

```
$ ./ctags --version
./ctags --version
Universal Ctags 5.9.0(692f5fd15), Copyright (C) 2015 Universal Ctags Team
Universal Ctags is derived from Exuberant Ctags.
Exuberant Ctags 5.8, Copyright (C) 1996-2009 Darren Hiebert
  Compiled: Feb  6 2022, 06:19:35
  URL: https://ctags.io/
  Optional compiled features: +wildcards, +regex, +gnulib_regex, +iconv, +debug, +option-directory, +xpath, +json, +interactive, +sandbox, +yaml, +packcc, +optscript, +pcre2
$ ./ctags --options=NONE -Dendm='endm;' -o - /tmp/sysreg.h | grep __msr_s 
./ctags --options=NONE -Dendm='endm;' -o - /tmp/sysreg.h | grep __msr_s 
ctags: Notice: No options will be read from files or environment
__msr_s /tmp/sysreg.h   /^#define __msr_s(/;"   d
```

The option `-D...` replaces the words `endm` in the `__ASSEMBLY__` area with `endm;`. The appended semicolon characters mitigate the indexer's confusion.

Comment: Hi Masatake, thank you very much! I installed universal ctags and used your method and it works now.